# How to call a component method from another component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component called **Users** witch is located in src/views/Users.vue, and I have another one called **UserPost** that is located in src/components/UserPost. So basically I want to invoke a method called **setUserNotification()** located in **UserPost** component and pass data to it from **Users** component. Keep in mind that the **UserPost** component is not used in **Users** and vice versa!

I've already thought of using this.$refs.element.method() but since i'm not using **UserPost** component inside **Users** component, using this option or even props is not possible at all. So I'm looking for another suggestion.

The code is below

Component Users :

```vue
    <template>
         <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <div>...</div>
              <bouton @click="onSubscribe(user.id)">Subscribe</bouton>
         </div>
        
    </template>
    
    <script>
         import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    
         export default {
            name: 'Users',
            computed: {
               ...mapState(['user', 'users']),
            },
            methods: {
                 onSubscribe(clickedUserId) {
                       ...
                       if(some condition evaluates to true ) {
                           // trigger setUserNotification(null, this.user[0].id, clickedUserId) method
                       }
                 }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Component UserPost :

```vue
    <template>
         <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
             <div>
                 <div>...</div>
                 <bouton @click="onLikeChange(pos.id)">Like</bouton>
             </div>
             <div>
                 <div>...</div>
                 <bouton @click="onDisLikeChange(pos.id)">Like</bouton>
             </div>
             <div>
                 <div>...</div>
                 <bouton @click="onCommentChange(pos.id)">Like</bouton>
             </div>
         </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
       import { mapState } from 'vuex'
       
        export default {
        name: 'UserPost',
        computed: {
             ...mapState(['user', 'posts']),
         },
        methods: {
              onLikeChange(postId) {
                  ...
                  if(some condition evaluates to true) { 
                     setUserNotification(postId, this.user[0].id)
                  }
              },
              onDisLikeChange(postId) {
                  ...
                  if(some condition evaluates to true) { 
                     setUserNotification(postId, this.user[0].id)
                  }
              },
              onCommentChange(postId) {
                  ...
                  if(some condition evaluates to true) { 
                     setUserNotification(postId, this.user[0].id)
                  }
              },
              setUserNotification(postId, currentUserId, clickUserId) {
                  ...
                  // I want this method to be called form Users component too!
                   
             }
          }
       }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: You could use vuex mutations. You can read more about it here https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: What is setUserNotification? Should be Vuex action. "So I'm looking for another suggestion" - you shouldn't have this problem when using global store, this is one of problem that it solves

Comment: It worked for me @MrFabio_25 . I actually trigger a vuex action form onSubscribe() method which in return commit a mutation and that mutation will changes a state variable, then I can watch that variable in my UserPost component and invoke setUserNotification.

Comment: @EstusFlask setUserNotification()  actually performs some actions in localStorage. And you're tight, it would be better if i used a globale variable from the beginning.

Comment: Try using mixin

Comment: Even though I've found a solution for my problem but i'm curious!  Why do I need to use sass mixin to resolve this kind of problems?! Sorry i didn't get you @Amaarockz

Comment: Don't you know there is concept called mixin in Vue?

Comment: Iam not talking about sass mixin buddy

Comment: Not actually! It's my first time hearing it 

Comment: I just found out that mixins are very handy options in vue when it comes to repetitive code. Thank you @Amaarockz :)